# Java Char addition makes no sense (to me)

Tags: java, char, addition

So I have this code here:

```
char a = '1';
char b = '2';
System.out.println(a+b); \\ Outputs 99
```

I want to know why, since this code:

```
char a = '1' + '2';

    System.out.println(a); \\ Outputs c
```

I want to enhance my primitive mind, please help a kindred spirit.

Comment: Every character corresponds to a [numeric value](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/basic_latin/list.htm), known as a *codepoint.*  Your code is actually doing `println( (int) a + (int) b )`, and `char a = (char) ((int) '1' + (int) '2')`.  If you want to concatenate strings, use strings, not chars.

Comment: I see, basicaly I treat the first one as an int and the second as a char. Thanks, that was enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are being added as their decimal numeric ASCII value.

The portion of the code that does `a+b` implicitly is adding them as integers.  So, if you run the following code:

```java
class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char ch = '1';
        char ch2 = '2';
        int num = ch;
        int num2 = ch2;
        System.out.println("ASCII value of char " + ch + " is: " + num);
        System.out.println("ASCII value of char " + ch2 + " is: " + num2);
    }
}
```

You will see that the output of each char is

> ASCII value of char 1 is: 49
>
> ASCII value of char 2 is: 50

So when you do this `System.out.println(a+b);` they get added as their integer value which turns out to be 99

Comment: Strange, I found here "https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character" that the value of 1 is 31 and of 2 is 32, adding them makes 63 which is 'c'  , the same goes if the char converts the 1 to the 'a' character which is 61 and 'b' which is 62 and adding them makes no sense with the result. Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's in Unicode (not ASCII) - look at this table (Wikipedia) and scroll down to the Unicode U+0031 - you will see that in ASCII, it has a different numeric (decimal) value https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: Oh I get it, the result was in ASCII while I was looking at Unicode. Well that resolves it.

Answer (score 1):

characters hold an  value in real;
when you write

```
char a = 49;
char k = '1'; // both of them holds same character because '1' code in ascii 49
```

and when you treat  two variable in arithmetic operation and if one of them type is(byte, short, or char) these types promote in int so

```
System.out.println(a+b); // both of them promote int
char c = a + b; // assign c, 99 which represents 'c'
```